# Getting a bound on the coefficients of the factor polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, divisors-multiples

Suppose $f(x):=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $|a_i|\leq M$ for each $i=0,\ldots ,n.$ Now suppose $g(x)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then is it possible to get a bound on the coefficients of $g(x)$ in terms of $M$ i.e. if $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^mb_ix^i$ then does there exist some $M^\prime $, which depends only on $M,n$ and $m$, such that $|b_i|\leq M^\prime$ for all $i=0,\ldots ,m$ ?

Comment: Simul-posted, without notice, to MathStackExchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206637/getting-a-bound-on-the-coefficients-of-the-factor-polynomial --- don't do that. 

Answer (score 12):

Gelfond's inequality is probably what you want here; see for example my book with Hindry, *Diophantine Geometry: An Introduction*, Proposition B.7.3. I'll state it for polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$, although there's a version that's true over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. The statement uses the projective height, so for a polynomial $f$ with coefficients $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, we let $$H(f) = \frac{\max|a_i|}{\gcd(a_i)}.$$ Then

**Proposition B.7.3 (Gelfond's inequality)** Let $f_1,\ldots,f_r\in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$, and for $1\le i\le m$, let $d_i$ denote the $X_i$ degree of $f_1f_2\cdots f_r$. Then
$$
  H(f_1)H(f_2)\cdots H(f_r) \le e^{d_1+\cdots+d_m}H(f_1f_2\cdots f_r).
$$

For the OP's question, we have $f$ is divisible by $g$, say $f=gg'$, so
$$
  H(g) \le H(g)H(g') \le e^{\deg f}H(gg') = e^{\deg f}H(f).
$$

Answer (score 11):

Completely explicit bounds are given by [Granville (bounding the coefficients of the divisor of a given polynomial, 1990, Monat. Math).](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BoundCoeff.pdf)

Comment: Extracting the bound for a casual reader: Granville proves that the $L_2$-norm satisfies $\|g\|_2\le\phi^m\|f\|_2$, where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. This implies $M'\le\phi^m\sqrt{n+1}M$.

Answer (score 5):

Define the height of a polynomial $f$ as $h(f)$, the max of the absolute values of its coefficients. Then (see e.g. Bombieri-Gubler Thm 1.7.2) $h(fg) \ge c(\deg f, \deg g)h(f)h(g)$, for some function $c(.,.)$ of the degrees. This gives what you want, except that $c$ is not very explicit.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see clearly how to use the information that the coefficients be integer numbers, apart the fact that $1\le |b_m|\le |a_n|$; therefore the following estimate is possibly non-optimal. However, it gives a simple and explicit bound, that also holds for complex coefficients.

By a [classic estimate on  the zeros of a polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Bounds_on_the_zeroes_of_a_polynomial), all (complex) roots of $f$ are bounded in modulus by $$1+\max_{0\le i < n}\frac{|a_i|}{|a_n|}\le M+1\, ,$$
because $|a_m|\ge1$. Since $b_i$ is the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial of some $m$ of the roots of $f$, times $b_m$, which is less that $M$ is size, we have

$$|b_i|\le M {m \choose i}(M+1)^i\, ,$$
so for instance
$$\sum_{i=0}^m|b_i|\le M':=M(M+2)^m\, .$$

Answer (score 4):

Any such bound must depend on $n$ or $m$, not just $M$, since once can take for instance $f(x) = x^n-1$ (so $M = 1$). Then depending on $n$, the cyclotomic factor $\Phi_n(x)$ has coefficients as large as you like: for example $\Phi_{105}(x)$ has coefficients of modulus $2$, $\Phi_{385}(x)$ has coefficients of modulus $3$, for further references see OEIS sequence A013594 (http://oeis.org/A013594).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously yes, since there are only finitely many such $f,g$ for each $M,n,m$.

Answer (score 1):

The review [Bounds on Factors of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3057.pdf) by John Abbott gives various such bounds and shows that none of them is strictly better than the others.